# How to export excel from the list using react data export

Tags: reactjs, export, react-data-table-component

> Hi I am new in React js. I need to export the data from the list (Data Table) in excel. I have already installed the react data component npm package, xlsx package, and react data export package. I gave the sample code below. When click the export button data is not downloaded.

This is code I got from google. I called the same code in my project. But It's working. Which libraries are best for exporting the data in excel (React Js.

````
## Simple Excel Export

```javascript
import React from "react";
import ReactExport from "react-data-export";

const ExcelFile = ReactExport.ExcelFile;
const ExcelSheet = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelSheet;
const ExcelColumn = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelColumn;

const dataSet1 = [
    {
        name: "Johson",
        amount: 30000,
        sex: 'M',
        is_married: true
    },
    {
        name: "Monika",
        amount: 355000,
        sex: 'F',
        is_married: false
    },
    {
        name: "John",
        amount: 250000,
        sex: 'M',
        is_married: false
    },
    {
        name: "Josef",
        amount: 450500,
        sex: 'M',
        is_married: true
    }
];

const dataSet2 = [
    {
        name: "Johnson",
        total: 25,
        remainig: 16
    },
    {
        name: "Josef",
        total: 25,
        remainig: 7
    }
];

class Download extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ExcelFile>
                <ExcelSheet data={dataSet1} name="Employees">
                    <ExcelColumn label="Name" value="name"/>
                    <ExcelColumn label="Wallet Money" value="amount"/>
                    <ExcelColumn label="Gender" value="sex"/>
                    <ExcelColumn label="Marital Status"
                                 value={(col) => col.is_married ? "Married" : "Single"}/>
                </ExcelSheet>
                <ExcelSheet data={dataSet2} name="Leaves">
                    <ExcelColumn label="Name" value="name"/>
                    <ExcelColumn label="Total Leaves" value="total"/>
                    <ExcelColumn label="Remaining Leaves" value="remaining"/>
                </ExcelSheet>
            </ExcelFile>
        );
    }
}
```

> Please let me know, how to export the data in excel using react data
> table data.

I searched in Google and youtube videos but, getting any related videos and documentation.
````